# How to stub Firebase for UI test Android?

Tags: android, firebase

Problem: I want to know which data go to Firebase Firestore and Firebase Authentication.

In my project, I'm using pure Firebase without RxJava or something else.

Here is my project on GitHub: https://github.com/Artemius-dev/Projemanag_Trello_Clone

Answer (score 0):

I have found only one solution so far.

- Firstly you need to make sure that you have good architecture in your app. Then make sure that you can     add DI to your project if you haven't done it already
- Secondly, make separate **DI** (Dagger or Hilt) for AndroidTest 
  *(**preferably not necessary** add some common Interface for example: to add Notes or Users to your app so you can implement the same Interface in your AndroidTests and inject it to your main app with new methods which will be only executed in your tests so you won't add anything in your production code)*
- Thirdly use Firebase Emulator Suite to work with not production data and database
  P.S (As I have seen so far the Firebase Emulator Suite is the best solution to test Firebase)